# Running in assembly related Issues while publishing/compiling a blazor client application in release mode

Tags: mono, blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side

I am getting below errors while trying to build/publish a blazer application (client version) in release mode. The application is running fine and is getting published as well in debug mode.

1. `Unhandled exception. Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'ExistingLibraryBuiltIn.NetFramework4.7.1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'  C:\...\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.0-rc1.20223.4\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets   284`
2. `ILLink failed with exit code -532462766.`

Project Details - 
[image: Project Detail]
**VS Version** - 16.7.0 Preview 2.0,
**Target Framework** - .Net Standard 2.1

Comment: Does this assembly build against netstandard2.1 because it looks like it targets .net 4.7 which is, I think, not supported by the linker (or by blazor)

Comment: yeah correct. it was building against netstandard2.1  which does not support .net 4.7. However, I tried changing it to netstandard 2.0 but then webassembly 3.2,0 does not support netstandard 2.0.

Comment: Yeah, my point was that you need to successfully build against netstandard2.1